# All electrical outlets are working well except one

Tags: receptacle, gfci

This house has a GFCI "Downstream?" circuit.  I see two outlets, each in the showerroom, labeled "GFCI Protected" but I do not see any outlet with a reset button or any red light anywhere in the house.

All outlets are working perfect except one.  The nonfunctional receptacle looks like it is the end of the circuit because when I unscrewed it and opened it it only had two wires attached to itself.

I thought the receptacle itself was the problem, and I swapped it with another receptacle in the basement which was not in use, but even after swapping, the one in the basement continues to work flawlessly but the one upstairs continues to be nonfunctional

What can I do at this point?

Comment: Is there a breaker in your panel with a TEST button on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem like that is either at the faulty receptacle, or at the outlet *before that*.  Check the one that feeds it.

As far as your GFCI, you'll want to find that.  Have you checked the breaker panel?  Or near the breaker panel?  I like to run a short stretch of conduit off the panel, then a 2-gang box with two GFCI deadfaces (or livefaces).

A GFCI is a *device*, not a receptacle.  You may be accustomed to seeing GFCI devices that are combo devices which also provide twin 120V receptacles.  There are other kinds of GFCI device.